# Google Chrome taking a long time to open and pages not loading

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I'm on Windows 10 and Chrome was fine for the first few weeks I got a new laptop. Afterwards it would take 10+ minutes for it to open, and when it does open, pages will always end up with an 'Aw snap'.

Edge works perfectly on the computer and I've tried several solutions for Chrome. Reinstallation doesn't work because it can't even uninstall properly. I tried the 'winsock' and 'netsh' solution proposed by a few forums, but it would only work until I put my computer back to sleep.

This is what's in my Chrome debug file:

```
[0810/172408:ERROR:process_info.cc(608)] range at 0xf065375000000000, size 0x223 fully unreadable
[0810/172408:ERROR:process_info.cc(608)] range at 0xf06537b600000000, size 0x223 fully unreadable
[0810/172408:ERROR:process_info.cc(608)] range at 0x0, size 0x223 fully unreadable
[0810/172408:WARNING:in_range_cast.h(38)] value 2353380267576 out of range
[0810/172408:WARNING:in_range_cast.h(38)] value 2353380265134 out of range
[0810/172408:WARNING:in_range_cast.h(38)] value 2353380267606 out of range
[0810/172408:WARNING:in_range_cast.h(38)] value 2353380267012 out of range
[0810/172408:WARNING:in_range_cast.h(38)] value 2353381027936 out of range
[0810/172450:ERROR:process_info.cc(608)] range at 0x1d2c375200000000, size 0x190 fully unreadable
[0810/172450:ERROR:process_info.cc(608)] range at 0x1d2c37b800000000, size 0x190 fully unreadable
[0810/172450:ERROR:process_info.cc(608)] range at 0x0, size 0x190 fully unreadable
[0810/172450:WARNING:in_range_cast.h(38)] value 1718476346936 out of range
[0810/172450:WARNING:in_range_cast.h(38)] value 1718476344494 out of range
[0810/172450:WARNING:in_range_cast.h(38)] value 1718476346966 out of range
[0810/172450:WARNING:in_range_cast.h(38)] value 1718476346372 out of range
[0810/172450:WARNING:in_range_cast.h(38)] value 1718477109408 out of range
[0810/172648:ERROR:process_info.cc(608)] range at 0xfe7f375400000000, size 0x1dd fully unreadable
[0810/172648:ERROR:process_info.cc(608)] range at 0xfe7f37ba00000000, size 0x1dd fully unreadable
[0810/172648:ERROR:process_info.cc(608)] range at 0x0, size 0x1dd fully unreadable
[0810/172648:WARNING:in_range_cast.h(38)] value 2052969141816 out of range
[0810/172648:WARNING:in_range_cast.h(38)] value 2052969139374 out of range
[0810/172648:WARNING:in_range_cast.h(38)] value 2052969141846 out of range
[0810/172648:WARNING:in_range_cast.h(38)] value 2052969141252 out of range
[0810/172648:WARNING:in_range_cast.h(38)] value 2052969903328 out of range
[0810/172735:ERROR:process_info.cc(608)] range at 0x82f837bc00000000, size 0x258 fully unreadable
[0810/172735:ERROR:process_info.cc(608)] range at 0x82f8382200000000, size 0x258 fully unreadable
[0810/172735:ERROR:process_info.cc(608)] range at 0x0, size 0x258 fully unreadable
[0810/172735:WARNING:in_range_cast.h(38)] value 2579177674296 out of range
[0810/172735:WARNING:in_range_cast.h(38)] value 2579177671854 out of range
[0810/172735:WARNING:in_range_cast.h(38)] value 2579177674326 out of range
[0810/172735:WARNING:in_range_cast.h(38)] value 2579177673732 out of range
[0810/172735:WARNING:in_range_cast.h(38)] value 2579178437024 out of range
```